# Segfault with multithreaded curl request

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, curl, libcrypto

I'm having some trouble with a C++ program here. Basically I've written a simple wrapper for http requests, with the ability to do multiple requests at once.
Works absolutely fine, but when I do httpS requests, it crashes randomly in multithreaded mode. I'm using curl and posix threads.
Backtrace looks like this:

```
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80996)[0x7fea9046d996]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x82b80)[0x7fea9046fb80]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0xf2)[0x7fea90470ae2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0(CRYPTO_realloc+0x49)[0x7fea8f9c6169]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0(lh_insert+0x101)[0x7fea8fa4bfb1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0(+0xe844e)[0x7fea8fa4e44e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0(ERR_get_state+0xde)[0x7fea8fa4eeee]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0(ERR_clear_error+0x15)[0x7fea8fa4f065]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4(+0x24e79)[0x7fea90f10e79]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4(+0x39ea0)[0x7fea90f25ea0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4(+0xf8fd)[0x7fea90efb8fd]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4(+0x219f5)[0x7fea90f0d9f5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4(+0x35538)[0x7fea90f21538]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4(curl_multi_perform+0x91)[0x7fea90f21d31]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4(curl_easy_perform+0x107)[0x7fea90f19457]
./exbot[0x40273a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7f6e)[0x7fea90cd6f6e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fea904e79cd]
```

Could this be a bug in libcrypto? 
Can I somehow tell curl not to use libcrypto? Any alternatives?
It only crahes wenn using httpS requests and works fine with even 10000 simultaneous http queries.

Cheers,
Thomas

Just for completeness my code:

```
// simple wrapper for http requests

#ifndef _REQUEST_H_
#define _REQUEST_H_


#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


//////////////////////////////////
// MACROS
//////////////////////////////////
#define ERR(_msg) std::cerr << __FUNCTION__ << ": " << _msg << std::endl


//////////////////////////////////
// REQUEST WRAPPER
//////////////////////////////////
typedef unsigned int uint;
class RequestWrapper
{
private: // non copyable
    RequestWrapper();
    RequestWrapper(const RequestWrapper &that);
    RequestWrapper &operator=(const RequestWrapper &that);

public:
    struct Response
    {
        Response() : msg(""), success(false) {}
        std::string msg;
        bool success;
    };

    static Response simpleGET(std::string url, uint timeout);
    static size_t write(char *content, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);
};


//////////////////////////////////
// GET
//////////////////////////////////
inline size_t RequestWrapper::write(char *content, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    std::string *buf = static_cast<std::string *>(userp);
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    for (uint i = 0; i < realsize; ++i)
    {
        buf->push_back(content[i]);
    }
    return realsize;
}
inline RequestWrapper::Response RequestWrapper::simpleGET(std::string url, uint timeout)
{
    Response resp;
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string buf;

    // send request
    buf.clear();
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl)
    {
        //ERR("libcurl init failed");
        return resp;
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, static_cast<void *>(&buf));
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        //ERR("libcurl request failed, CODE: " << res);
        return resp;
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    // done
    resp.msg = buf;
    resp.success = true;
    return resp;
}


//////////////////////////////////
// MULTITHREADED REQUEST
//////////////////////////////////
class RequestList
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> _reqs;
    static void *sender(void *payload);
    static pthread_mutex_t _mutex;

public:
    inline void add(std::string request)
    {
        _reqs.push_back(request);
    }

    inline void clear()
    {
        _reqs.clear();
    }

    std::vector<std::string> send(uint timeout) const;

    struct Payload
    {
        std::string url;
        std::vector<std::string> *out;
        uint tout, index;
        Payload(std::string url,
                std::vector<std::string> *out,
                uint tout, uint index) : url(url), out(out), tout(tout), index(index) { }
        Payload() : url(""), out(NULL), tout(0), index(0) { }
    };
};


//////////////////////////////////
// SEND MT REQUEST
//////////////////////////////////
pthread_mutex_t RequestList::_mutex;
void *RequestList::sender(void *payload)
{
    Payload *pl = static_cast<Payload *>(payload);
    RequestWrapper::Response resp = RequestWrapper::simpleGET(pl->url, pl->tout);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    if (resp.success)
    {
        pl->out->at(pl->index) = resp.msg;
        std::cerr << ".";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "x";
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
    return NULL;
}
inline std::vector<std::string> RequestList::send(uint timeout) const
{
    std::vector<std::string> resp;
    resp.resize(_reqs.size());
    Payload *payloads = new Payload[_reqs.size()];
    pthread_t *tids = new pthread_t[_reqs.size()];

    // create mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(&_mutex, NULL);

    // prepare payload and create thread
    for (uint i = 0; i < _reqs.size(); ++i)
    {
        payloads[i] = Payload(_reqs[i], &resp, timeout, i);
        pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, RequestList::sender, static_cast<void *>(&payloads[i]));
    }

    // wait for threads to finish
    for (uint i = 0; i < _reqs.size(); ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    }
    std::cerr << std::endl;

    //destroy mutex
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&_mutex);

    delete[] payloads;
    delete[] tids;
    return resp;
}


#endif
```

Comment: Your crash is somewhere inside `realloc` in libc.  That suggests heap corruption to me.  If so, the bug could be anywhere.

Comment: According to [this](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Libcrypto_API), OpenSSL, including `libcrypto`, isn't thread-safe by default. You can supply the necessary locking functions to OpenSSL, or build libcurl with a different thread-safe SSL library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Libcrypto` is part of OpenSSL, which is [not thread-safe](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Libcrypto_API#Thread_Safety) unless you provide the necessary callbacks. According to the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html), on a POSIX-compliant system (which has thread-local `errno`) the default thread-id implementation is acceptable, so you just need a locking function:

```
void locking_function(int mode, int n, const char *file, int line);
```

This function will need to maintain a set of `CRYPTO_num_locks()` mutexes, and lock or unlocks the `n`-th mutex depending on the value of `mode`. You can read the documentation for more details. The libcurl website actually has [some sample code](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/opensslthreadlock.html) showing how to do this.

Alternatively, you can build libcurl with a different SSL library that is thread safe, such as [GnuTLS](http://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Thread-safety.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! A simple sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev 
solved my problem.

Comment: @th0ms0n Yep, if you have a pre-built package that's easy :)